# Text font size ration between different screens

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I have to define text font size with different screen size. Assuming that the following dimen.xml is the default:

```
<dimen name="font_5">5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_6">6sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_7">7sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_8">8sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_9">9sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_10">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_11">11sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_12">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_13">13sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_14">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_15">15sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_16">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_18">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_20">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_21">21sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_25">25sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_26">26sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_30">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_35">35sp</dimen>
```

I have created a dimen.xml for all other dimensions (w820dp, sw600dp, sw800dp) and in those files i declared the same ratio (X2) as below

```
<dimen name="font_5">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_6">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_7">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_8">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_9">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_10">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_11">22sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_12">24sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_13">26sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_14">28sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_15">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_16">32sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_18">36sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_20">40sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_21">42sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_25">50sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_26">52sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_30">60sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_35">70sp</dimen>
```

I have developed an example app using a tablet 7'' for testing but I see that in the smartphone the font size is a bit smaller than expected. In the other hand, if I adjust the fonts using the smartphone as pilot, in the tablet they became too big.
Assuming that I want to keep unchanged the default dimen.xml, what's the ratio that I should use to define the others dimen.xml?

Comment: did you check tablet default font size? it medium ,small?

Comment: Small and also the smartphone is small

Comment: i think, its best you follow google https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes tutorials. its explained in greater detail.

Comment: This page doesn't tell me what I'm asking for

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you with text font size with different screen size**

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
```

Comment: @LorenzoVincenzi if you find the answer please post here, I am also working on it now.